# How would I return which link is clicked on in an iframe

Tags: html, iframe, click

I am trying to write a web page to play my music when I am out of the house.
I have a directory listing of the music in an iframe. And i have a javascript audio player function to play the albums.
I just need to link the two together by passing what is clicked on in the directory listing iframe to the javascript audio player.

I have tried using the following to no avail.

iframeDoc.addEventListener and iframeDoc.attachEvent

I am not sure whether these work on the links in the iframe or just on the iframe itself (the documentation on these web pages is quite obscure).

I have done lots of googling and come across JQuery and DOM. Neither of which I understand.
I have also read that I can use the postMessage API but no details on how to use it were given.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Thank You.
```

This question has now evolved. I have stopped using an iframe with a directory listing and I now have the music listing in the main html page. And I can send a parameter of the album to be played to the audio player. But the new problem is that the audio player will not play the selected album.
The music is listing is of the following format :

```
100 Greatest One Hit Wonders 80<br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/100&nbsp;Greatest&nbsp;One&nbsp;Hit&nbsp;Wonders&nbsp;80/CD1>100 Greatest One Hit Wonders 80/CD1</a><br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/100&nbsp;Greatest&nbsp;One&nbsp;Hit&nbsp;Wonders&nbsp;80/CD2>100 Greatest One Hit Wonders 80/CD2</a><br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/100&nbsp;Greatest&nbsp;One&nbsp;Hit&nbsp;Wonders&nbsp;80/CD3>100 Greatest One Hit Wonders 80/CD3</a><br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/100&nbsp;Greatest&nbsp;One&nbsp;Hit&nbsp;Wonders&nbsp;80/CD4>100 Greatest One Hit Wonders 80/CD4</a><br>
101 Pirate Radio Hits<br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/101&nbsp;Pirate&nbsp;Radio&nbsp;Hits/CD1>101 Pirate Radio Hits/CD1</a><br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/101&nbsp;Pirate&nbsp;Radio&nbsp;Hits/CD2>101 Pirate Radio Hits/CD2</a><br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/101&nbsp;Pirate&nbsp;Radio&nbsp;Hits/CD3>101 Pirate Radio Hits/CD3</a><br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/101&nbsp;Pirate&nbsp;Radio&nbsp;Hits/CD4>101 Pirate Radio Hits/CD4</a><br>
<a href=audio_player.php?album=Music/2001&nbsp;A&nbsp;Space&nbsp;Odyssey>2001 A Space Odyssey</a><br>
7 Superb Albums of US Psychedelic Rock 1967-72<br>
```

and so on ...

One of these lines is passed to the audio player.
The code for audio_player.php is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Audio Player</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="audio.css">
    <script src="audio.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body><div id="demo">
    <!-- (A) AUDIO TAG -->
    <audio id="demoAudio" controls></audio>

    <!-- (B) PLAYLIST -->
    <div id="demoList">
<?php
   $_GET["album"];
#   echo $_GET["album"];
   $album_to_play = $_GET["album"];

#   $music_dir = "Music/Fleetwood Mac Discography/1969 - Fleetwood Mac - English Rose";
   $music_dir = "$album_to_play";
  // (B1) GET ALL SONGS
#      $songs = glob("$music_dir/*.{mp3,webm,ogg,wav}", GLOB_BRACE);
      $songs = glob("$music_dir/*.{mp3,webm,flac,m4a,ogg,wav}", GLOB_BRACE);

      // (B2) OUTPUT SONGS IN <DIV>
      if (is_array($songs)) { foreach ($songs as $k=>$s) {
        $name = basename($s);
        printf("<div data-src='%s' class='song'>%s</div>", rawurlencode($name), $name);
  }} else { echo "No songs found!"; }
    ?></div>
  </div></body>
</html>
```

and then there is the audio.js file which is :

```
var aud = {
  // (A) INITIALIZE PLAYER
  player : null,   // html <audio> element
  playlist : null, // html playlist
  now : 0,         // current song
  init : () => {
    // (A1) GET HTML ELEMENTS
    aud.player = document.getElementById("demoAudio");
    aud.playlist = document.querySelectorAll("#demoList .song");

    // (A2) LOOP THROUGH ALL THE SONGS, CLICK TO PLAY
    for (let i=0; i<aud.playlist.length; i++) {
      aud.playlist[i].onclick = () => aud.play(i);
    }

    // (A3) AUTO PLAY WHEN SUFFICIENTLY LOADED
    aud.player.oncanplay = aud.player.play;

    // (A4) AUTOPLAY NEXT SONG IN PLAYLIST WHEN CURRENT SONG ENDS
    aud.player.onended = () => {
      aud.now++;
      if (aud.now>=aud.playlist.length) { aud.now = 0; }
      aud.play(aud.now);
    };
  },

  // (B) PLAY SELECTED SONG
  play : id => {
    // (B1) UPDATE AUDIO SRC
    aud.now = id;
    aud.player.src = "Music/101 Pirate Radio Hits/CD1/" + aud.playlist[id].dataset.src;

    // (B2) A LITTLE BIT OF COSMETIC
    for (let i=0; i<aud.playlist.length; i++) {
      if (i==id) { aud.playlist[i].classList.add("now"); }
      else { aud.playlist[i].classList.remove("now"); }
    }
  }
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", aud.init);
```

I have been playing with these files all day and cannot get the audio player to play the album.

```
    Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

             Thank You.
                  David.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am wondering if this is actually possible. Might it be better to manually create a directory listing and put onclick statements in each of the links.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my edited question.

The solution was simple. instead of separating the words in the parameter to the php script with ampersandnbsp; (I had to put it like that otherwise it just shows as a space.) I used %20 instead.

There were a few other little tweaks s well. Like using the php unlink and symlink commands to create a link to the album being played.

I knew I could work it out in the end. It just took me a while.

```
                      Thank You.
                           David.
```